# Convert 12 hour date format into 24 hour format & vice versa in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have a date from a UIControl. I get date as string such as `06-12-2016 01:25 PM`. Now I want to convert it into a format as `2016-12-06 13:25:00` I have tried below code t do so but it just gives me wrong date for ex. `2016-12-06 18:55:00`. I have used below code for this:

```
 func converStingToDate(str_date:String)->String
  {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str_date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

  }
```

Please suggest me a better code. Also if you guys can help me to understand all this date formatting concept how it is done ?

Answer (score 3):

The code is correct and the date is correct (although you should use `h` for 12-hour hour).

Your time zone is `UTC+0530` and `print()` displays the date in `UTC`.

If you need to `print` the correct local time set the time zone of the formatter to UTC:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")`
```

Comment: Converting a local time string to a different local time string does not require setting any specific timezone on the formatter. The only change that needs to be made is to fix the first date format by changing the `H` to `h`. Once that is done the code works fine. If anything, the locale of the formatter should be set to `en_US_POSIX` to ensure there is no issue due to the setting of 24-hour time on the device doesn't get in the way.